# Changing a lightbulb in my bathroom Light/fan combo

Tags: bathroom, light, fans

Is there an alternative type of light fan combo for the bathroom ceiling that does not involve using the springs to change the lightbulb. The frustration level is unbelievable!

Comment: Can we have a photo, to better answer your question, preferably one when it is open

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to *eliminate the light bulb*. Light bulbs are a hold-over from the days when a typical light bulb lifetime was 1,000 hours. An LED bulb can last 25,000 hours or more. An *integrated LED* can last even longer, because it can be better designed for heat dissipation than a screw-in or plug-in bulb. Even at 25,000 hours, if you have a fixture used 4 hours a day that's 17 years! By which time it is quite likely the fan will have failed or the bathroom renovated, etc. A similar fixture using an incandescent bulb would require a change every year - quite a difference.

That being said, there is a non-zero risk that an integrated LED fixture will fail in a much shorter period of time. Stick to a major brand, look for a long warranty (DLC normally requires a *minimum* of a 5-year warranty) and hope for the best.

Comment: My bathroom light/fan combo has a heat bulb; perhaps that's the case for the OP, too.

Comment: A heat bulb is a different thing. Some combinations don't have heat at all. Of the ones that do, some use a bulb, others (like mine) use the same type of heating element that you have in a space heater - i.e., can be replaced but not simply like a bulb.

Comment: Yes of course - I was just pointing out that the OP hasn't quite given us enough info to be sure that they are dealing with a standard light bulb.